# Discretization data numeric and convert to a integer matrix?

Tags: r, discretization

I discretize a dataset using **RWeka** in R.

```
library(RWeka)
m2 <- Discretize(Species ~., data = iris)
View(m2)
```

But I want the output as an integer matrix.

For example: all the outputs of the package **Discretization** in R are integer matrix.

Comment: The columns are factors which in a way (read about it) are already integers. You might want to keep it that way, just learn to use factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for `as.integer`:

```
data.frame(lapply(m2, as.integer))
```